# Unable to install ubuntu 13.10

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I created a 18 GB unallocated partition for Ubuntu from Windows 7 by shrinking a drive, the unallocated space is just after the `C:\` drive.

I then started Ubuntu 13.10 from a Live USB, to the place where we can select  "install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7."

But in my case the option was "install Ubuntu inside Windows 7", after selecting it when I pressed 'Continue', the process just restarted instead of going forward.

I am using a 32-bit Lenovo g580.

Comment: don't select install alongside option if you had drives other than `c`.

Comment: Follow this [Install Ubuntu 13.10](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest) official guide & select **Something else** under installation type & then point to the unallocated partition you've made at the installation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Many people often think that you will have to make changes to your hard drive prior to installing Ubuntu. Such is not the case. Perhaps the reason the installer keeps kicking back to the beginning is because it sees the unallocated space of the hard disk and doesn't know what to do with it, so it goes back to let you choose the "something else" option.

If you don't feel like going into manual partitioning, I recommend expanding your Windows partition back into the space you cut before and then choosing the "install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7" option in the installer. You'll be able to resize the Windows partition from here. Just make sure you're not cutting into used space, or else you'll lose all of your files!

Comment: I tried this, But then also the option is install ubuntu inside win7 and when i tried the same bootable pen-drive on another laptop then it is showing the option install ubuntu along side win7 and at this point i'm having 3 disk partitions 119gb 191gb and 154gb after expanding c-drive

Comment: @Harishbhutra I think the "install Ubuntu inside Windows 7" might be referring to a WUBI installation, which I could recommend as well, since you're on Windows 7 and not Longhorn (Vista beta, didn't work with WUBI). If you want to go for the WUBI installation, make sure your Windows 7 partition is expanded and you can use the WUBI installer found at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer. It has it's perks, such as the ability to uninstall Ubuntu just as you would a piece of software, and there have been no reported issues with Windows 7.